# The file “IMG_00001.MOV” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, swift3

When try convert video url to data then getting error:

```
"The file “IMG_00001.MOV” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."
```

Here is my code:

```
let videoUrl = Dictionary.object(forKey: "videoUrl") as! String

do {
    let vidUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoUrl)

    let videoData = try Data.init(contentsOf: vidUrl)
    videoMainData = videoData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithLineFeed)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`videoMainData?.write(to: vidUrl`

try adding this lines  after..
                                  `videoMainData = videoData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithLineFeed)`

Comment: but bro  `videoMainData = videoData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithLineFeed)` this line is not execute because of process going to catch after try statement

Comment: let vidUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoUrl)

        let videoData = NSData.init(contentsOf: vidUrl)
        do {
            try videoData?.write(to: vidUrl)
            
        }
        catch {}

Comment: Try the above lines,, it worked for me in my project., i just converted URL to NSData, like the above..